# SQL Server Local publications folder is not found under replication SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-replication

Local publication folder is not found under the replication but local subscriptions folder is available. My current version is SQL Server 2014.

[image: find the below sql screenshot]

Comment: The version of SSMS isn't relevant - its the version of SQL Server (`select @@version`) thats of interest.

Comment: Also - is this possibly an **Express** edition of SQL Server you're using?

Comment: @DaleK  the version of SQL server is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) , Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 18362: )

Comment: Always update ([edit]) your question, don't add important information in comments.

Comment: The **Express** edition can only function as a subscriber in a replication -> therefore, works as expected / designed. If you need to be a publisher, you need to use Standard or Enterprise editions of SQL Server